# Vertically center a drawing area in Python & GTK+3

Tags: python, gtk3, glade

I have created a dialog with a drawing image inside it. The area is scaling
when I change the dialog size. When it does that, the drawing area sticks to the top an isn't vertically aligned. 
To my best understanding, this widget isn't supporting `yalign`, so I will need an `AspectFrame`, but when I add an aspect frame with glade, the `DrawArea` isn't shown.

Here are the relevant parts of my working code:

```
class MyDialog(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.glade_file = os.path.join(abspath(dirname(__file__)), 'dialog.glade')

        self.builder.add_from_file(self.glade_file)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        # get widgets
        self.dialog = self.builder.get_object('dialog')
        self.box = self.dialog.get_child()

        da = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.box.pack_start(da, True, True, 0)

        da.surface = None
        da.connect('draw', self.draw)
        da.connect('configure-event', self.configure_event_cb)
```

The code creates the following:

[image: funny dialog]

To add the aspect frame, I did the following:

```
da = Gtk.DrawingArea()
#self.box.pack_start(da, True, True, 0)
self.frame = self.builder.get_object('aspectframe1')
self.frame.add(da)
```

But this results in the `DrawingArea` not being shown and the following error:

```
 GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple: assertion 'dest_height > 0' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_draw4.py", line 134, in configure_event_cb
    clear_surface(w, h, widget.surface, self.pb)
  File "test_draw4.py", line 29, in clear_surface
    Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, pb, 0, 0)
TypeError: Argument 1 does not allow None as a value
```

Please help me vertical center that `DrawingArea`

Comment: You should add the code of the dialog here - for two reasons: We can't test without it, and some of the properties of the glade file can influence the alignment too. That said, a GtkAlignment widget sets you move the widget around.

Comment: I was trying to avoid GtkAlignment, because it's deprecated.